# What is the algorithm used by programming languages to eval ASTs?

Tags: lisp, scheme, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

What is the algorithm used by programming languages to eval their ASTs?

That is, suppose we have 4 basic functions, `/*+-`. What is a basic algorithm that will correctly eval any AST in the form of, for example:

```
(+ (- (* 3 2) (+ (/ 5 2))) (* 2 4))
```

My doubt is actually what happens if the evaluation of a node returns something that still have to be evaluated. For example, in Scheme, the evaluation of `((lambda (a) (+ a 2)) 3)` would be `(+ 3 2)`. But this could be evaluated again into 5. So how does the language determine when to stop evaluating a form?

Answer (score 2):

You're totally misunderstanding how Scheme/Lisp evaluation works. I'll use the example you gave:

```
(+ (- (* 3 2) (+ (/ 5 2))) (* 2 4))
```

To evaluate a list, we evaluate each of the elements. The first is expected to return a procedure (I'm ignoring the special case of syntax operators), the rest can return arbitrary values. We call the procedure with the rest as arguments.

At the top level, this is a list of 3 elements:

1. `+`
2. `(- (* 3 2) (+ (/ 5 2)))`
3. `(* 2 4)`

Each of these is evaluated. The first is a variable whose value is a procedure (Scheme's built-in addition function). The others, being lists, require recursion into the evaluation algorithm. I'm going to skip describing the second one, because of its complexity, and go to the third: `(* 2 4)`.

This is a list of 3 elements: *, 2, and 4.  As above, * is the multiplication function. 2 and 4 are literals, so they evaluate to themselves.  So we call the multiplication function with the arguments 2 and 4, and it returns 8.

The complicated second argument goes through the same process, just with several more levels of recursion.  It eventually returns 4.  So we then call the multiplication function with the arguments 4 and 8, and it returns 32.

Your second example is processed similarly.  At the top, you have a list of two elements:

1. `(lambda (a) (+ a 2))`
2. `3`

Each of these is evaluated. Lambda is special syntax that parses its contents and returns a procedure that evaluates its body in a context where the parameter variables are bound to arguments, so the first returns a procedure that adds 2 to its argument and returns that. 3 is a literal, so it just returns the number 3. We then call the procedure with the argument 3, it adds 2 to it and returns 5.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you give, the execution will stop at 5, since it is a literal value and represents itself.  This is not hard to test for.  You might as well ask how a function that traverses a list in depth knows how to stop (in fact, you should, since in Scheme this is the same thing).

In Scheme, any compound expression should eventually resolve to one of the 7 primitive datatypes or the empty list, unless it becomes trapped in an infinite loop.  If you want to know in advance if the expression will resolve, well, that's an interesting problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be asking the wrong question, but I will try:

Until it gets a result that it can work with.  In your example you're asking about when an interpeter stops evaluating an expression... its 100% language depedent and would be a completely different answer if you were to ask about a compiler. For your Scheme example, you would need to read the Scheme specification ([R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/)).

So it is defined by the writer of the interpreter. If a single literal (or even variable) is the expected result of an expression in my language, then it would stop there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different algorithms.

**Alternative 1:** You could compile the AST to an intermediate representation which is more linear.  Your code could be compiled to something like the following:

```
a <- 3 * 2
b <- 5 / 2
c <- a - b
d <- 2 * 4
e <- c + d
return e
```

This is easy to evaluate, since it is just a sequence of instructions.  Most of the instructions have the same format: `X <- Y OP Z`, so the evaluator will be very simple.

**Alternative 2:** You can compile alternative #1 to machine code or byte code.

```
li      r3, 3
muli    r3, 2
li      r4, 5
divi    r4, r5, 2
subf    r3, r3, r4
li      r4, 2
muli    r4, r4, 4
add     r3, r3, r4
blr
```

**Alternative 3:** You can compile alternative #1 to a special form called SSA, or "single static assignment", which is similar to #1 but the LHS of every assignment is unique, and special "phi" nodes are used to combine values from different branches.  SSA can then be compiled to machine code or byte code.

**Alternative 4:** You can evaluate the AST by recursive descent.  This is covered thoroughly in most books on Scheme / Lisp.

**Alternative 5:** You can use recursive descent to convert the code to stack machine code, and then evaluate that.  Something like:

```
push 3
push 2
mul
push 5
push 2
div
sub
push 2
push 4
mul
add
ret
```

**Alternative ∞:** There are plenty of other techniques.  The books written on this subject are *thick.*